# AngularJS $watch causes my page to break

Tags: angularjs, watch

New at Angular and trying to get examples in book to run.  Example is about $watch method.  The following code works fine:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>StartUp Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form ng-controller='StartUpController'>
    Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()" ng-model="funding.startingEstimate" />
    Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
</form>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    function StartUpController($scope) {
        $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };

        $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
            $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
        };
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But, when I add the $watch method and simplify the template, the whole page fails with the following:

- No startingEstimate is displayed at all inside the input element
- The {{funding.needed}} variable is displayed as a literal string on the page

The code that fails is:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>StartUp Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<form ng-controller='StartUpController'>
    Starting: <input ng-model="funding.startingEstimate" />
    Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
</form>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    function StartUpController($scope) {
        $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };

        $scope.$watch('funding.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);

        $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
            $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
        };
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No idea what's causing this to happen...need help plz :-)

Comment: js console error ? can you provide a jsfiddle ? btw test `$scope.$watch($scope.funding.startingEstimate, computeNeeded);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a bug in the code. You're missing `$scope` in front of computeNeeded. As well, place `$scope.computeNeeded` above the `$watch` because the pointer isn't declared until after the `$watch` currently.

```
$scope.computeNeeded = function() {
        $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
};

$scope.$watch('funding.startingEstimate', $scope.computeNeeded);
```

Alternatively, I would do it this way, which would allow you to put `needed` wherever you wanted.

```
function needed() {
    $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
}

$scope.computeNeeded = needed;

$scope.$watch('funding.startingEstimate', needed);
```

Comment: Thanks @Pete :-)  This works fine.  I tracked the answer down as well (below) and it's pretty much the same.  Would vote this up, but don't have enough reputation :-(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Pete!

I was able to track it down as well :-)

It's pretty much the same as @Pete provided, only I've combined the var declaration with the actual function.

The code that works declares computeNeeded as a var and the $watch comes after it in the code.
(Note: I had the $watch both before and after in the original and both didn't work)

The working code:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>StartUp Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<form ng-controller='StartUpController'>
    Starting: <input ng-model="funding.startingEstimate" />
    Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
</form>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    function StartUpController($scope) {
        $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };

        var computeNeeded = function() {
            $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
        };

        $scope.$watch('funding.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```